# Keyframes in Firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I have searched high and low for help on this both on this site and elsewhere but can't seem to figure out what is happening and why it's not working.  I have been able to get it to work in Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE.  Would you be willing to take a look and help me out? I apologize if the code doesn't show correctly, this is my first post. (URL www.djopus.com)

```
.flexslider {
border: 0;
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
height: auto;
-webkit-animation:uplighting 10s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-animation:uplighting 10s;
animation:myfirst 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes uplighting
{
0% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,46,46,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,46,46,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,46,46,1);}
20% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,245,46,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,245,46,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,245,46,1);}
40% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(63,245,46,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(63,245,46,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(63,245,46,1);}
60% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,255,242,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,255,242,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,255,242,1);}
80% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,13,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,13,255,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,13,255,1);}
90% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(221,0,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(221,0,255,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(221,0,255,1);}
100% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(255,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(255,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(255,0,0,1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes uplighting
{
0% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,46,46,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,46,46,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,46,46,1);}
20% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,245,46,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,245,46,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(245,245,46,1);}
40% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(63,245,46,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(63,245,46,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(63,245,46,1);}
60% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,255,242,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,255,242,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,255,242,1);}
80% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,13,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,13,255,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(0,13,255,1);}
90% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(221,0,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(221,0,255,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(221,0,255,1);}
100% {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(255,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(255,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 65px 16px rgba(255,0,0,1);}
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes uplighting
{
0% {background:red;}
25% {background:yellow;}
50% {background:blue;}
100% {background:green;}
}
```

Comment: Why your standard syntax `@keyframes` don't match up with the prefixed ones?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change the name of animation from "myfirst" to "uplighting" :)

It's result of very complicated code which could be easily simplified. All the modern desktop browser support for animation without vendor-specific prefixes. You only need -webkit for Safari on some smartphones, if your really need it. For more detailed information refer the following article: [Blink HTML text tag and its alternatives](http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/blink-html-text-tag-alternatives), CSS Animation compatibility is explained there.

So, CSS should be like the following:

```css
.flexslider {
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  height: auto;
  animation: uplighting 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes uplighting
{
  0% { background: red }
  25% { background: yellow }
  50% { background: blue }
  100% { background: green }
}
```

Try this and it you'll sure enjoy the result!